# Colloquial Contraction Confusion

Tags: slang, て-form, colloquial-language, contractions, song-lyrics

This is taken from one of the mindless pop songs I shouldn't even be listening to:

> なんてったって　ラッキー！

I know what なんて and ラッキー mean, of course, but I can't figure out in a way that makes sense to me what the contracted forms after なんて are. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I believe that ったって is a reduction of 言ったって, which combined with なんて likely means roughly "no matter what I say/you say/etc."

Comment: Sounds good to me. なんてったって = なんと言ったって = なんと言っても.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a contraction and not 達て, which would meant it was something they wished for, and they thought the person was lucky?   With the little つ in there to represent how it was said?